# How to Scrape Specific Content using Beautifulsoup / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the number of likes on each comments on youtube.

My overall code loops through / scrolling down but for simplicity i'm only showing the part which poses me problems. I'm new to web scraping. Here's what I've tried:

```
page_url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQG7m1BFeRc"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Me/Chrome Web 
Driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(page_url)
html_source = driver.page_source
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
soup=bs(html.text,'html.parser')
soup_source=bs(html_source,'html.parser')
```

I then try to extract the number of likes:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="style-scope ytd-comment-action- 
buttons-renderer"):
    a=str(div.text)
    print(a)
```

But this returns nothing. When i inspect the soup_source content, I can see the following where the info that i want to scrape is kept:

```
<span aria-label="473 likes" class="style-scope ytd-comment-action- 
buttons-renderer" hidden="" id="vote-count-left">
    473
```

etc

I've tried a few things like:

```
html = driver.(By.ID, 'vote-count-left')
```

but it does not work. If someone could please help it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver_path = r'C:/Users/Me/Chrome Web Driver/chromedriver.exe'
driver_path = r'D:\Programming\utilities\chromedriver.exe'

page_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQG7m1BFeRc"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(page_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="owner-name"]/a')))
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 768);')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'vote-count-left')))

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = [element.text.strip() for element in soup.find_all('span', {'id': 'vote-count-left'})]

result
```

Output:

```
['1.9K', '153', '36', '340', '474', '1.5K', '296', '750', '0', '18', '2K', '20', '17', '8', '192', '459', '56', '10', '0', '19']
```

This is actually more complex than it seemed at first glance, because YouTube does *not* load the comments section *until* you actually scroll down. Therefore, I had to include logic to wait for the page to be fully loaded and scroll down, and then to wait more until the comments actually loaded.

Also, you should have been looking for `span`, not `div` - that was the cause of your original query not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

get all span by ID **#vote-count-middle** and get the atribute **aria-label** that contains the likes and exact only the numbers using a regular expression.

Note: This code hasn't been tested but has a clear path for what you are trying to achieve.

```
    import re
    reg = re.compile(r'(?<=[0-9]\s[A-Z]\s)[0-9\-\s]+')

    likeArray = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vote-count-middle"]')
    for row in likeArray:
    # Extract from span the value 000 Likes on internal html attribute
    value = row.get_attribute("aria-label").text
    if reg.search(value):
       # Remove text (Likes text)
       result = reg.search(value)
       # Print result
       print(result)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ,sorry for my late reply i slept early last night. I get the following error msg: TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
html = """
  <span id="vote-count-left" class="style-scope ytd-comment-action-buttons-renderer" aria-label="474 likes" hidden="">
    474
  </span>

  """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
data = soup.find_all("span")
for i in data:
     print(i.text)
```

Output:

```
    474
```

Comment: Have you actually viewed the YouTube page source?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ,sorry for my late reply i slept early last night. In the page source i can see the following but i'm unable to extract: <span aria-label="473 likes" class="style-scope ytd-comment-action-buttons-renderer" hidden="" id="vote-count-left">
        473
      </span> Or if you take a look at youtube likes pages they are not easy to scrape, the rest is ok but the likes i'm having problems :-(